# MPLAB assembly issue code jumps

Tags: pic, assembly

I am having some issues with what I think to be good code. This is for a uni assignment but this is not the code I'm submitting. This is a test file to understand how it all works. Some of this code was given in the assignment: the snum & binary sections.

I need to get each number in snum in turn and display the equivalent binary number on a 7 segment for a few seconds. It runs in the debugger until 'call binary', then it jumps back to start (after that instructino).

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

```
; Directive sets processor type .............................

        list  p=16F84A
        #include "P16F84A.INC"

; Set configuration fuses ...................................

        __CONFIG _CP_OFF & _WDT_OFF &_PWRTE_ON & _RC_OSC

; Code protection off, watchdog timer off, power up timer on, RC Clock

        errorlevel  -302        ;No warnings, register not in Bank 0
PCL         EQU     02  ; Program Counter Low
PORTB       EQU     06  ; Port B Data Register
TRISB   EQU 86  ; Port B Data direction register
STATUS  EQU 03  ; Status register
RP0 EQU 05  ; Bank select bit
timer       EQU     0C  ; GPR1 used as delay counter
point       EQU     0D  ; GPR2 used as table pointer

    org 000
    goto    start

snum    addwf   PCL,F
    dt  "0001035020"    ;Substitute your student number
                        ;(10 ASCII digits)

;       Pattern table for seven segment display on Port B ..

binary  addwf   PCL,F
    retlw   b'00111111' ;Set display to 0
    retlw   b'00000110' ;Set display to 1
    retlw   b'01011011' ;Set display to 2
    retlw   b'01001111' ;Set display to 3
    retlw   b'01100110' ;Set display to 4
    retlw   b'01101101' ;Set display to 5
    retlw   b'01111111' ;Set display to 6
    retlw   b'00000111' ;Set display to 7
    retlw   b'01111111' ;Set display to 8
    retlw   b'01101111' ;Set display to 9

; Initialise Port B (Port A defaults to inputs)........

start   bcf STATUS,RP0  ;Bank select 0
    clrf    PORTB   ;Clear Port B data latches
    bsf STATUS,RP0  ;Bank select 1
    movlw   0x00    ;
    movwf   TRISB   ;Set port B lines to output
    bcf STATUS,RP0  ;Bank select 0

; MAIN LOOP
nextdigit   movlw   d'10'
    subwf   point,W
    btfsc   3,2
    goto    nextdigit
    movf    point,W
    call    snum
    call    binary
    movwf   PORTB
    NOP
    NOP
    incf    point
    goto    nextdigit

    end
```

Comment: Instead of using numbers for registers (`btfsc 3,2`) I'd recommend you using the register names (`btfsc STATUS, Z`) for readability.

Comment: And use banksel for changing banks, instead of fiddling with the status bits.

Comment: Have to fiddle part of the assignment learning etc. Thanks for the 3 and 2 thing I have status and Z setup in the larger file but it wasn't working the above was thrown together from many files

Comment: There is a lot more that could be said about your code, much of which you won't like, but since you've already accepted a answer its pointless anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't initialize the `point` register. That means it can hold *any* value when you start looping the `nextdigit` loop! Try adding a `clrf point` under the `start` label.

For debugging: in MPLAB -> View -> File Registers, you can see the value of `point` during runtime.