# Read and Write Protection to pic18f4520?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, microchip

I am working on pic18f4520 using MPLAB C18 compiler. I have just completed a project (Asked questions about it earlier,see my other posts) and now I want to lock the data of the micro-controller so that no one can read or write it any more. Can anyone plz upload sample of a code on how to protect data in pic18f4520.[image: See images and plz tell my why there is a syntax error]

[image: where is the asm file?]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by adding one line of code in your assembly file

```
__CONFIG _CP_ON
```

More info on this [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70465/mplab-assembly-issue-code-jumps) and [this](http://www.microchip.com/forums/m631297.aspx)

Read chapter 15.6 from [this book](https://books.google.rs/books?id=CB9GaAU1dwsC&pg=PA758&lpg=PA758&dq=PIC%20Microcontroller:%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Software%20code%20protection&source=bl&ots=HhddC5qC8f&sig=vSC6PcvUcwLmwoOAMDhPngmf1p8&hl=sr&sa=X&ved=0CBwQ6AEwAGoVChMI_tnD7KaMxwIVxQ8sCh3DlweZ#v=onepage&q=PIC%20Microcontroller%3A%20An%20Introduction%20to%20Software%20code%20protection&f=false)

Comment: I don't have a assembly file . I have a C source file and when I write this command line into it , compiler gives a syntax error any guess why.

Comment: fix error, compile, and you will have .asm file beside .c source file.

Comment: see the pics and plz tell me the error. I also tried writing " __CONFIG _CP_ON " as " #pragma config CP = ON " but it gives a different error saying CP unknown @Junior

Comment: It worked when I wrote " #pragma config CP1=ON " THANKS....

Comment: NOW, do I have to define other two bits CP2 and CP3? second ques. How can I test that it is write or read protected? @Junior

Comment: Code protection can be tested by writing .hex file to your PIC microcontroller, if after that write you cannot write to it anymore code protect is successfully activated. @prog_SAHIL

Answer (score 2):

If you want to embed it in your C code you can use the pragma `config` directive to set the fuses. From the [PIC18 configuration settings addendum](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51537a.pdf) it looks like the PIC18F4520 has four code protect blocks so you'd need the following to protect those and the boot block:

```
#pragma config CP0 = ON
#pragma config CP1 = ON
#pragma config CP2 = ON
#pragma config CP3 = ON
#pragma config CPB = ON
```